# Input text box scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I currently am having a problem with HTML `<input type="text">`,
as in the Google Chrome browser, if I use the below CSS,
when I type text into the box, I am able to highlight the text
and drag it up and down, as if it is scrolling a little 2px,
due to the text larger than the input box.

Can anyone help me solve my problem, and prevent the dragging to scroll up and down the 2px?

Many thanks!

```
input {
    border: 0px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: inherit;
    margin: -1px;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: You have a negative margin. Doesn't that mean the textarea is larger than its size?

Comment: I am trying to make the input box fit exactly the text input, without the small 1px margin around if u see all input boxes.

Comment: Can anyone help me? Here's an example of my problem: http://picopicopixel.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Specify:

```
input{ vertical-position:middle; line-height: * your input field height * }
```

And specifically for IE specify:

```
 input{ vertical-position:bottom; }
```

otherwise IE will show the text in the upper part of the input.

Comment: Adjusting line-height fixed things for me. IE does not like line-height > height of input box.

Comment: Specify: line-height == height of input box. That should fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    border: 0px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: inherit;
    margin: -1px;
    background: none;
    line-height:10px
}
```

reducing the line height should solve your problem. And don't use negative margin on a textbox. If you want to position it, wrap it in a div and then position, else if you doing it with a label, use negative margin for label to pull the input close to it.

Comment: Hi! thanks for helping. but i still can't solve my problem. I tried using 10px, 1px, and 0px line-height but it still did not work. I am trying to make it look the same as texts with Courier font, as the input box space them apart at all margins. I am still able to drag and scroll them up and down in Chrome with all kinds of line-height.

Comment: please give me link to your webpage

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to add the margin:-1px. Can you try viewing it again? Without the margin:-1px; , it does not align properly to the numbers at the side.

Comment: instead of margin:-1px; use
margin:0 0 0 -1px;
this will reduce margin only on left hand side

Comment: I have to reduce the margin on top and bottom, since I have to align it correctly in the height. I have updated picopicopixel.com/index.html so that it is clearer now.